# How to disable automatic line break when inserting two curly braces in vim?

Tags: vim, curly-braces, line-breaks

Whenever I type two curly braces (`{{`), I get something like that:

```
{
|
}
```

`|` is used to describe the position of the cursor.

This behaviour is totally annoying, e.g. when using different template engines which reserve this syntax for variables.

How can I find out where that behaviour comes from? And how do I shut it off?

Thanks

Comment: Is there anything else besides `{{` that you type, that could trigger a mapping (e.g., `<Enter>`?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find out where it comes from:

```
:verbose imap {{
:verbose map {{
```

Look for the mapping with 'i' (insert mode mapping) and see where it is defined

If that's not it, it could be an abbreviation:

```
:verbose abbrev
```

Comment: I get `no mapping found` for both `{` and `{{`. :-(

Comment: Updated my question with the output of different `:verbose` calls. Nothing that catches my eye. (Except that I probably should remove the freaking rails bundle ;-))

Comment: Why did you insert a slash (`:verbose map \{` instead of `:verbose map {`)?

Comment: I just guessed that I need to escape those braces. Without the slashes, I get `no mapping found`.

Comment: With the slash you get a very funny match. I can only guess the mapping is for 'character wise select mode' (?) which I didn't know exists. I'd by now start eliminating plugins by disabling all, enabling one by one. Sry, but if the commands listed don't show it, there seems to be no other option

Comment: @balu ensure that you have the same filetype loaded to check for the maps

Comment: The funny thing is that this seems to happen across all file types. Weird. Thanks for your help, I'll keep you updated on the solution.

Comment: HAH! I got it! `:verbose imap {{` gave me what I needed to know. It was the `autoclose` plugin. Would you alter your answer? I'll mark it as accepted then! Thanks again!

Comment: @balu: that is great news. have updated the answer. I'm going to have to read the help text for these again, because I was convinced `:map` should list mappings for _all modes_... Thank you too

Comment: From autoload.vim: `As of 1.1, if you type the open brace twice ({{), the closing brace will be pushed down to a new line.`

Comment: @sehe, I was not aware of this also, but `:map` does not show imaps. Try it by yourself and you'll notice that there is no line starting with `i`. The Vim help *map.txt*, in it's first chapter, more exactly in line 112, introduces the `:{x}map` commands to list the available maps. Note that, `:map` itself is set to show only `nvo` maps. Also is important to point that the `v` mode is actually a double map mode. Mapping to `v` means mapping to `x` and `s` (visual and select mode respectively) so that's why some `xs` maps appear in the `:map` list.

Comment: @sehe, and regarding my initial comment on stealing, I was just kidding as you posted what I was writing at that moment :-P

Comment: haha, by the way look at the last line of `:h map-modes`, right before `:h mapmode-x`

Comment: @sidyll: Yeah, I remember reading quite a few of these dry-wit hidden lines in the vim docs. I used to print them and read them front to back when I started out with vim :)

Answer (score 4):

If you use the same plugin as me, [AutoClose](https://github.com/vim-scripts/AutoClose), then you can type `<leader>a` (which is `,a` for me, it depends on your `<leader>` key).

`<leader>a` toggles On or Off for autoclose.

Comment: Yup the `autoclose` plugin was indeed the problem. But I was more interested in finding out how to identify the causes. ;)